# Trial vs realization

Tags: random-variable, terminology

In the context of random variables, is "trial" synonymous with "realization"? For example, is a Bernoulli trial one realization of a Bernoulli random variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of Bernoulli trial is *flipping a coin* (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

*Before the coin is flipped*, you can define an *observable* random variable $X$ which will keep track of the outcome of the coin flip (i.e., heads or tails). Specifically:

$X = 1$ if the coin flip will land heads and 
   $X = 0$ if the coin flip will land heads.

The reason the random variable $X$ is *observable* is because its value will become known to us after flipping the coin.  As remarked by @whuber, there are also unobservable random variables, which will not be a concern to us in this answer. The values of unobservable random variables will remain unknown to us even after conducting a random experiment such as a coin flip.

As pointed out by @whuber in his answer, the observable random variable $X$ will "keep track of the experimental outcomes associated with a Bernoulli trial by assigning numbers to them in systematic, consistent ways".  Furthermore, assigning numbers to these experimental outcomes facilitates posing and answering quantitative questions involving the random variable $X$.

You won't know with certainty what the value of $X$ is before you perform a single flip - in other words, you are uncertain about whether the coin flip will land heads (in which case the value of $X$ would be equal to $1$) or tails (in which case the value of $X$ would be equal to $0$). However, if you were to perform a large number of coin flips with a fair coin, you would expect half of those flips to land heads and half to land tails. In other words, you would expect the probability that $X = 1$ to be 1/2 and the probability that $X = 0$ to be 1/2.

*After the coin is flipped*, you will observe the actual value of the observable random variable $X$. This value is called a realization of $X$. For example, the realized value of $X$ may be 0 (if the coin flip produced tails). Note that this value is now known with certainty. The uncertainty that was in place before conducting the coin flip with regards to possible value of $X$ was replaced with certainty about the actual value of $X$ observed after conducting the coin flip.

So many people struggle with the concept of *random variable* because they don't understand that:

1. A random variable keeps track of the outcome of a random experiment (e.g., flipping a fair coin);
2. The value of the random variable is unknown only before conducting the random experiment;
3. After conducting the experiment, the value of the random variable is fully known if the variable is observable.

Comment: (+1) Some (many?) authors make a distinction about (2) and (3), calling such random variables *observables.*  Other random variables may be involved in a model that are not observed: their values remain unknown even after the experiment.  Concerning (1), it would be helpful to emphasize that random variables keep track of experimental outcomes by assigning *numbers* to them in systematic, consistent ways.  This is an important tool for creating a *quantitative* question (and therefore amenable to mathematical analysis) out of one that (to laypeople) may appear not to be quantitative at all.

Comment: Great points, @whuber!  I revised my answer to incorporate them explicitly - please have a look and let me know if any further edits are needed.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Thanks for this detailed explanation. As I understand, a key property of a random experiment (flipping a coin in the above discussion) is that it can be repeated (imaginatively, at least). You allude to this when you  talk about "performing a large number of coin flips with a fair coin". Is the $X$ from each "repetition" different?

Comment: @rishai: You are right about repetition being a key property of a random experiment. The **definition** of $X$ is the same across various repetitions of a random experiment, but the **realized (or observed) value** of $X$ may change from one repetition to another.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Got it. About the meaning of "trial": I read in Papoulis 2002 p. 51 "A trial is the toss of the coin once.", but in the Wikipedia article you mentioned (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), it seems a trial is the experiment itself. So "trial" can refer either to a realization of an experiment, or the experiment itself, depending on the context?

Comment: @rishau: Your experiment is something you define.  You can define your experiment # 1 to consist of a single coin toss (i.e., a single Bernoulli trial). Or you can define your experiment # 2 to consist of 10 coin tosses (i.e., 10 Bernoulli trials).  For experiment # 1, you can define your random variable X as the outcome of the single trial. For experiment # 2, you can define  your random variable X as the number of trials out of 10 in which you obtained a head.

Comment: So if your experiment was designed to include a single Bernoulli trial, then you are right that the experiment and the trial are the exact same thing. But if your experiment was designed to include multiple, independent Bernoulli trials, the experiment is a collection of these trials. The context will make it clear what situation you are in.